# Ember getting stale values while setting object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a user form which takes some inputs and does a Submit;

So every time on Submit, the following code gets called;

```
var newObj = {};
// Then I set newObj.prop1, newObj.prop2, etc
Ember.set(this.get('myServerParams'), 'someMainObj.propertyObj', newObj);
```

So I create a new object from scratch & then set it to 'myServerParams'

However there is a strange issue which I observe. 
In this.get('myServerParams').someMainObj.propertyObj, in certain cases, the previous values get added (e.g. Say I select 'prop2', then also newObj.prop1 = 'oldProp' gets added) & submitted to the server.

With the above code, how is that possible ?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do there. `set` should only take 2 arguments, shouldn't it?

Comment: I think that is if you do this.set()...But Ember.set() works with 3 args

Comment: @testndtv could you maybe provide a jsfiddle? If you reproduce the issue there it will be easier to understand and help. Here's the link ember-twiddle.com

Comment: Kind of difficult to reproduce, since I make server calls...But could you just let me know how I could destroy the object and be sure each time an entirely new object gets created..(even though I do use new Object())